# sbt install tries to find SshResolver

Tags: sbt

Installing sbt is supposed to be easy, but I've tried a number of different things without any luck.  When I execute "sbt sbt-version" (see below) it throws an exception as it can't find the SshResolver which is not available in the sbt-launcher.jar (other resolvers are).  So why is it trying to use SSH?  My system is Windows 7 x64 connected wirelessly to a comcast cable modem.  Since sbt-launcher is run by the java application, I've checked Avast to make sure that it is able to open any port for both input and output.

I run sbt as administrator and get the following output in the cmd window below and below that the log file.

I'm anxious to get this going as I'm losing time staying with the Coursera Reactive Programming Course.

Thanks!

Tom

---

```
C:\Windows\system32>sbt sbt-version
Getting net.java.dev.jna jna 3.2.3 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3

        ==== local: tried

          C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\local\net.java.dev.jna\jna\3.2.3\ivys\ivy.xml

        ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

          http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.
2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== Maven Central: tried

          http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom


        ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried

          https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/j
na/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
        Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.types
afe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

        Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.mave
n.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see C:\Users\tom\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve jna 3.2.3

C:\Windows\system32>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Here is the LOG FILE:

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

setting 'ivy.default.settings.dir' to 'jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/sbt/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to 'C:\Windows\System32\.'
setting 'ivy.default.conf.dir' to 'jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/sbt/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VsftpResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.version.PatternVersionMatcher in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.trigger.LogTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntBuildTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IvyRepResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.signer.bouncycastle.OpenPGPSignatureGenerator in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.conflict.RegexpConflictManager in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SFTPResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.updatesite.UpdateSiteResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntCallTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.MirroredURLResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.packager.PackagerResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.DualResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VfsResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.JarResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.obr.OBRResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define glob matcher: org.apache.ivy.plugins.matcher.GlobPatternMatcher was not found.
setting 'java.runtime.name' to 'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment'
setting 'sun.boot.library.path' to 'c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin'
setting 'java.vm.version' to '24.45-b08'
setting 'java.vm.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'java.vendor.url' to 'http://java.oracle.com/'
setting 'path.separator' to ';'
setting 'java.vm.name' to 'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM'
setting 'file.encoding.pkg' to 'sun.io'
setting 'user.country' to 'US'
setting 'user.script' to ''
setting 'sun.java.launcher' to 'SUN_STANDARD'
setting 'sun.os.patch.level' to 'Service Pack 1'
setting 'java.vm.specification.name' to 'Java Virtual Machine Specification'
setting 'user.dir' to 'C:\Windows\System32'
setting 'java.runtime.version' to '1.7.0_45-b18'
setting 'java.awt.graphicsenv' to 'sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment'
setting 'java.endorsed.dirs' to 'c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\endorsed'
setting 'os.arch' to 'amd64'
setting 'java.io.tmpdir' to 'C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Temp\'
setting 'line.separator' to '
'
setting 'java.vm.specification.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'user.variant' to ''
setting 'os.name' to 'Windows 7'
setting 'sun.jnu.encoding' to 'Cp1252'
setting 'java.library.path' to 'c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\giter8\;D:\proguard4.8\bin;d:\JOGL1.1.1\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby-1.9.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\;;.'
setting 'java.specification.name' to 'Java Platform API Specification'
setting 'java.class.version' to '51.0'
setting 'sun.management.compiler' to 'HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers'
setting 'os.version' to '6.1'
setting 'user.home' to 'C:\Users\tom'
setting 'user.timezone' to 'America/Los_Angeles'
setting 'java.awt.printerjob' to 'sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob'
setting 'file.encoding' to 'Cp1252'
setting 'java.specification.version' to '1.7'
setting 'sbt.log.format' to 'true'
setting 'java.class.path' to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\jansi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\sbt-launch.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\classes'
setting 'user.name' to 'tom'
setting 'java.vm.specification.version' to '1.7'
setting 'sun.java.command' to 'SbtJansiLaunch sbt-version'
setting 'java.home' to 'c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre'
setting 'sun.arch.data.model' to '64'
setting 'user.language' to 'en'
setting 'java.specification.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'awt.toolkit' to 'sun.awt.windows.WToolkit'
setting 'java.vm.info' to 'mixed mode'
setting 'java.version' to '1.7.0_45'
setting 'java.ext.dirs' to 'c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext'
setting 'sun.boot.class.path' to 'c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfr.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\classes'
setting 'java.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'file.separator' to '\'
setting 'java.vendor.url.bug' to 'http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/'
setting 'sun.io.unicode.encoding' to 'UnicodeLittle'
setting 'sun.cpu.endian' to 'little'
setting 'sun.desktop' to 'windows'
setting 'sun.cpu.isalist' to 'amd64'
setting 'ivy.default.ivy.user.dir' to 'C:\Users\tom\.ivy2'
setting 'ivy.home' to 'C:\Users\tom\.ivy2'
setting 'ivy.cache.dir' to 'C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\cache'
no default cache defined: set to C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\cache
setting 'ivy.checksums' to 'sha1,md5'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to 'C:\Users\tom\.sbt\boot'
setting 'basedir' to 'C:\Users\tom\.sbt\boot'
:: resolving dependencies :: org.scala-sbt#boot-jna;1.0
confs: [default]
validate = true
refresh = false
resolving dependencies for configuration 'default'
== resolving dependencies for org.scala-sbt#boot-jna;1.0 [default]
loadData of org.scala-sbt#boot-jna;1.0 of rootConf=default
== resolving dependencies org.scala-sbt#boot-jna;1.0->net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3 [default->default(compile)]
loadData of net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3 of rootConf=default
using redefined-public to resolve net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3
redefined-public: Checking cache for: dependency: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3 {default=[default(compile)]}
redefined-public: no namespace defined: using system
no ivy file in cache for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: tried C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\cache\net.java.dev.jna\jna\ivy-3.2.3.xml
redefined-public: no latest strategy defined: using default
local: no namespace defined: using system
no ivy file in cache for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: tried C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\cache\net.java.dev.jna\jna\ivy-3.2.3.xml
trying C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\local\net.java.dev.jna\jna\3.2.3\ivys\ivy.xml
tried C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\local\net.java.dev.jna\jna\3.2.3\ivys\ivy.xml
local: resource not reachable for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: res=C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\local\net.java.dev.jna\jna\3.2.3\ivys\ivy.xml
local: no ivy file found for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3
typesafe-ivy-releases: no namespace defined: using system
no ivy file in cache for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: tried C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\cache\net.java.dev.jna\jna\ivy-3.2.3.xml
trying http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
tried http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
ERROR: Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
typesafe-ivy-releases: resource not reachable for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: res=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
typesafe-ivy-releases: no ivy file found for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3
Maven Central: no namespace defined: using system
no ivy file in cache for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: tried C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\cache\net.java.dev.jna\jna\ivy-3.2.3.xml
trying http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
ERROR: Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
Maven Central: resource not reachable for net/java/dev/jna#jna;3.2.3: res=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
Maven Central: no ivy file found for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3
sonatype-snapshots: no namespace defined: using system
no ivy file in cache for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: tried C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\cache\net.java.dev.jna\jna\ivy-3.2.3.xml
trying https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
tried https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
HTTP response status: 404 url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
CLIENT ERROR: Retrieval of /net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom from M2Repository(id=snapshots) is forbidden by repository policy SNAPSHOT. url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
sonatype-snapshots: resource not reachable for net/java/dev/jna#jna;3.2.3: res=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
sonatype-snapshots: no ivy file found for net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3
WARN: module not found: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3
WARN: ==== local: tried
WARN:   C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\local\net.java.dev.jna\jna\3.2.3\ivys\ivy.xml
WARN: ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
WARN:   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
WARN: ==== Maven Central: tried
WARN:   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
WARN: ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried
WARN:   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom
Nbr of module to sort : 0
resolved ivy file produced in C:\Users\tom\.sbt\boot\resolution-cache\resolved-org.scala-sbt-boot-jna-1.0.xml
:: downloading artifacts ::
:: resolution report :: resolve 43708ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
WARN: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
WARN: ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
WARN: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
WARN: :: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found
WARN: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Nbr of module to sort : 0
report for org.scala-sbt#boot-jna;1.0 default produced in C:\Users\tom\.sbt\boot\resolution-cache\org.scala-sbt-boot-jna-default.xml
resolve done (43708ms resolve - 0ms download)

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3

==== local: tried

 C:\Users\tom\.ivy2\local\net.java.dev.jna\jna\3.2.3\ivys\ivy.xml

==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

 http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

==== Maven Central: tried

 http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

==== sonatype-snapshots: tried

 https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:238)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:695)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:780)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:703)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:575)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:233)
at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Checks.java:105)
at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:99)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:52)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Checks.java:100)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:266)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jnaLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.jnaLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:106)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:85)
at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:281)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
at SbtJansiLaunch.main(SbtJansiLaunch.java:4)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
at xsbt.boot.Pre$.error(Pre.scala:22)
at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Checks.java:105)
at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:99)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:52)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Checks.java:100)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:266)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jnaLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.jnaLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:106)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:85)
at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:281)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
at SbtJansiLaunch.main(SbtJansiLaunch.java:4)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
```

---

Comment: Can you check IF you can access http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom via a browser? Are you perhaps connecting Internet via proxy? Could you run `set JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=yourserver -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"` followed by `sbt`?